# need help getting specific values from an array and sorting them from highest to lowest

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm using these values:

```
8
9 5 7 -5 13 -4 11
7 5 -3 12 -5 17 -3
25 7 12 -3 5 -5 7 -5 3
14 5 12 -3 10 -7 8
5 1 -40
33 5 15 -5 9 -3 8
11 5 -12 8 -5 12 -3
13 5 3 -4 25 -5 3
```

The first number is the ammount of basketball players there are in a team, the first number of every row is the player's kit number, the second number is how many times he sat on the bench or played on the court during the match, and the other numbers is the ammount of time he played (if the number is positive) and how long he sat on the bench (if the number is negative). What I need to do is to figure out which 5 players started the match (if the 3rd number of a row is positive, it means the player started the match). Then I need to take the kit numbers of the players who started the match and sort them from lowest to highest. Here's my progress:

```
void skaitymas()
{
    int minnum = starters[0];
    ifstream fd ("u1.txt");
    fd >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        fd >> k[i] >> t;
        for (int j = 0; j < t; j++){
            fd >> zaidnez[j];
        }
        if (zaidnez[0]>0){
            // if I write cout << k[i]; here I get all the kit numbers but not in order
            starters[i] = k[i]; // here I'm trying to set the values to another array but it doesn't really work, I'm not sure how to do it properly.
        }
    }
    fd.close();
}
```

Comment: This looks like a real good use case for some OOP.  You create a `Player` object and then read the data into a vector of Players.  Then it becomes pretty simple to analyze the data from there.

Comment: Just check for 2nd index in each row(use a loop). If positive, put the 0th index of that row inside a set(only if you know that kit numbers will be unique, if not push them into a vector and then sort the vector).

Answer (score 0):

Here is solved using `vector` as suggested in the comments.
Note that I'm using `cin` for convenience, but the same can be done with your `ifstream fd`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    vector <vector <int> > players;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++ )
    {
      vector <int> player;
      int val;
      std::string line;
      std::getline(cin, line);
      std::istringstream iss(line);
      while ( iss >> val) {    
        player.push_back(val);
      }
      players.push_back(player);
      if((player.size()>3)&&(player[2]>0))
      cout << player[0] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So in `players` you have a `vector` containing all players (which are also `vector`s). Then you can sort it using `std::sort`.

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/JGK56W)

Output:

> 9 25 14 33 13

Comment: You don't need the `cin.ignore`.

Comment: Note:  your `player` vector is *recreated* in each `for` loop.  My understanding is that the OP wants results from analysis of all players.

Comment: If you are going to post a code answer, please indicate how it is different or how it solves the OP's question.

Comment: Updated taking into consideration @ThomasMatthews 2nd comment

Comment: @ThomasMatthews if commented `cin.ignore` line, then don't work properly, see: http://ideone.com/DWZprx, can you explain why is not needed?

Comment: My bad.  I didn't see you were using `getline` to read the other numbers.